# How can I set a UILabel as my accessory view while till having the UITableViewCell display a DisclosureIndicator?

Tags: swift

I am trying to create a UITableViewCell that has both a label and a DisclosureIndicator displayed on the right of the cell, how would I go about this?

Answer (score 1):

Just create your own custom UITableViewCell class and layout the UIButton and UILabel in the nib